# x86 assembly input and out

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

```
section .bss ; you can change
 user_input: resb 256 ;256 byte of memory is reserved and can be accessed through the name user_input
 user_input_size equ $- user_input

section .data ;you cant change
 output: db "Enter your print statement: "
 output_size equ $- output

section .text ;assembly code
global _start

_start:
 mov eax, 4
 mov ebx, 1
 mov ecx, output
 mov edx, output_size
 int 80

mov eax, 3
mov ebx, 0
mov ecx, user_input
mov edx, user_input_size
int 80

push ecx ; not sure about this
push edx ; not sure about this

mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 0
pop ecx
pop edx
int 80


mov eax, 1
mov ebx, 0
int 80
```

i want to print out "Enter your print statement: ", have the user input a statement and have that inputted statement returned to the screen. The first part is working. The others not so much. When the user enters a statement is it stored eax or ecx(user_input).

Comment: Did you search?  I found several examples with a google search for `site:stackoverflow.com x86 read input and print it assembly -21h`.  (`int 21h` is the DOS ABI; we have to weed that out because people insist on wasting their time and cluttering up stack overflow with legacy 16-bit crap.)

Comment: Sweet. Thanks Peter Cordes.

Comment: @PeterCordes if i have a question about the answers in those threads, should i just post in them?

Comment: Yes, ask a new specific question if you have one that you can't sort out by reading the man pages for the relevant system calls, running it under `strace ./a.out`, and other standard debugging methods.  (see the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info)